# JavaScript Variable Syntax: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript variable I am using in conjunction with Google Maps API.

For some reason I am getting the error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

I believe it has to do with the 4th line in the following code snip. I do not expect this abut it seems like there is a common syntax issue with the below?

```
var EditForm = '<p><div class="marker-edit">'+
            '<form method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">'+
            '<label for="pType"><span>Product:</span>'+'<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeyup="iwproductFilter()" placeholder="Search for names..">'+'&nbsp;'+
            '<a onclick="document.getElementById('userInput').value = ''; iwproductFilter();" style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;"</a>'+'&#10006'+
            '<ul id="myUL">'+'<li id="1a"><a>Adele</a></li>'+'<li id="1b"><a>Agnes</a></li>'+'<li id="1c"><a>Billy</a></li>'+
            '<li id="1d"><a>Bob</a></li>'+'<li id="1e"><a>Calvin</a></li>'+'<li id="1f"><a>Christina</a></li>'+'<li id="1g"><a>Cindy</a></li>'+'<li id="1h"><a>Doug</a></li></ul>'+
            '<select name="pType" class="save-type"><option value="restaurant">Rastaurant</option><option value="bar">Bar</option>'+
            '<option value="house">House</option></select></label>'+
            '<label for="pUserName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pUserName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>'+
            '<label for="pDesc"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Add Product</button>';
```

Comment: It's your inline JS in the anchor's onclick. You should probably extract that into its own external code.

Comment: How would you suggest this?

Comment: Using Javascript to add HTML that contains inline Javascript is kind of icky to start with! But yes, escaping the `'` quote marks is your immediate problem.

Comment: `pointer;"</a>` isn't right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes `'` in `document.getElementById('userInput').value = ''` aren't  escaped.

Change it to `document.getElementById(\'userInput\').value = \'\'` and it'll work

Answer (score 3):

To avoid any issue, you could use template litterals :

```
var EditForm = `<p><div class="marker-edit">
            <form method="POST" name="SaveMarker" id="SaveMarker">
            <label for="pType"><span>Product:</span><input type="text" id="userInput" onkeyup="iwproductFilter()" placeholder="Search for names..">&nbsp;
            <a onclick="document.getElementById('${userInput}').value = ''; iwproductFilter();" style="font-size:16px;cursor:pointer;"</a>&#10006
            <ul id="myUL"><li id="1a"><a>Adele</a></li><li id="1b"><a>Agnes</a></li><li id="1c"><a>Billy</a></li>
            <li id="1d"><a>Bob</a></li><li id="1e"><a>Calvin</a></li><li id="1f"><a>Christina</a></li><li id="1g"><a>Cindy</a></li><li id="1h"><a>Doug</a></li></ul>
            <select name="pType" class="save-type"><option value="restaurant">Rastaurant</option><option value="bar">Bar</option>
            <option value="house">House</option></select></label>
            <label for="pUserName"><span>Place Name :</span><input type="text" name="pUserName" class="save-name" placeholder="Enter Title" maxlength="40" /></label>
            <label for="pDesc"><span>Description :</span><textarea name="pDesc" class="save-desc" placeholder="Enter Address" maxlength="150"></textarea></label>
            </form>
            </div></p><button name="save-marker" class="save-marker">Add Product</button>`;
```

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than escaping items

Answer (score 1):

Your string is written by single quotes. So if you again want to use single quotes inside your string, you need to escape them using `\`. You can also replace the string `''` with double quotes `""`.

What about 4th line, you need not just put the variable but concatenate it as the rest of your string lines.

```
'<a onclick="document.getElementById(' + userInput + ').value = ""' 
^                                    ^               ^            ^
open    separate string part       close             open         close
```

If your *userinput* is just the `id` of the element, not a variable you need to escape them.

```
'<a onclick="document.getElementById(\'userInput\').value = \'\''
```